# Access multidimentional PHP array in Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script running a SQL query on my MSSQL Server instance. I get a good result. Now I'm trying to manipulate its result from $.ajax  But It seems that the "Object.field_name" way of acessing fields in an obejct table is not working in my Jquery Ajax (maybe because there is more that one line returned)

The table is json_encoded in php. Could you help me access these data and put it in a global vairable ?

PHP script

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');  //Newly added
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

  try {
    $hostname = "SQLEXPRESS";
    $port = 1433;
    $dbname = "MY_BD";
    $username = "user";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   }catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }

 $stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.emp");
 $stm->execute();

$table_1 = array();
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $table_1[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($table_1);


?>
```

Javascript script

```
var my_data ;

function get_my_data(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/My_Script/test_1.php',
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(result) {
      my_data = result;
      alert(my_data); //This will alert [Object object]
      alert(my_data.id); //This will alert undefined ; id being on of the 
      //result fields
    }
  });
}

alert(my_data); //This will alert undefined (not even [Object Object]
//as if the global variable my_var can't be access in the $.ajax part
$( document ).ready(get_my_data);
```

Whithout Jquery Ajax, the output of my php script in the browser is :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"John","sal":"1525.21","age":"45"}]
[{"id":"2","name":"Cecily","sal":"854.75","age":"28"}]
[{"id":"3","name":"Alfred","sal":"945.28","age":"37"}]
```

Comment: for starters is `success` firing? where is your ajax error handler? Your CORS configuration looks to be lacking several other `Access-Control` headers

Comment: What do you get if you alert `my_data[0].id`? Looks like your results are an array of objects, although I can't tell if you have shown three separate results, or 1 result with 3 rows? Also, you'll get way more data if you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` and check your browser's console for the output, which should let you explore the output.

Comment: @charlietfl for my CORS (forget about them. I added one line but they are ok ) ... Next is the error hadling. Dont bother about it as this script was used in a case "Hello world " before and it worked. The only thing now is the fact that it a multidimentional array and also that I want to use a global variable

Comment: @xjstratedgebx Ok I think the problem is solved. `my_data[0].id` just printed "1".... BUT I stil cant get it in my global variable `my_data`

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. You can't access the data in alert outside of it because it hasn't been returned yet. You need to consume it inside success. Don't use alert for debugging data/variables....use console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

1: You are not accessing `my_data` properties correctly. `my_data` is an array of objects.  To access the first object's id property, use `my_data[0].id`.

2: The last `alert(my_data);` directly above `$( document ).ready(get_my_data);` is called before `my_data` gets defined. This is because `$.ajax` is asynchronous.

Comment: ok I get. I was able to access it with `my_data[0].id`  Any idea how I could define my_data with the data coming from the success function and use is later ?

Comment: One way to use it `later` is to put the code that needs to run after `my_data` is defined within the `success` callback.  Another way is to use `promises`.  If you have a nontrivial amount of logic, `promises` are generally better.  Also have a look into `generators`.

Comment: omg. For a beginner thats a lot. I hot using it in the success callback will help me. I'll look into promises and generators. Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access `my_data` from that scope because `$.ajax` is asynchronous.

But i can suggest you to do this way

```
var my_data;

function get_my_data() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/My_Script/test_1.php',
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(result) {
      my_data = result;
      //alert(my_data); // this is an array you can't alert it do console.log(my_data)
      //alert(my_data.id); // you can't access id directly because it's an array
      // rather you can do this way loop/map over it will return each array item
      my_data.map(function(data) {
        alert(data.id);
      })
    }
  });
}

//as if the global variable my_var can't be access in the $.ajax part
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_my_data();
});
```

Comment: *"you have to call that ajax with async: false"* shouldn't even be a topic of discussion other than to say never use it.... it is a terrible and flawed concept. It is also now deprecated by browser vendors and warnings are being logged in console if you do use it

Comment: @charlietfl good tip, i will update my answer with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a way to iterate over the results.

```
$(my_data).each(function(index,value) {
    alert(value.id);
});
```

should work. As for making this global. Declare the variable outside the call and set it in the success and you should be able to access it. The reason why it is undefined for you is that ajax is asynchronous and that call is executed before the server returns the value.

Comment: cool. If I'm correct then I have defined it as I should in the success. But since ajax is asynchronous, at what point am I going to be able to access it ? (changing the position in the script will help ?

Comment: There is no saying when you will be able to access. You could try a `setTimeout` for 5 seconds or so but it is a bad practice. You should have whatever code that needs to run after you get the values from your ajax request, called from the `success` callback function. You can set async:false in your ajax request but it is not the right way to do things.

Comment: Ok mate thank you. Raphael said that too. I'll just add the code in the success callback